# Turn off cookies in Tornado

Tags: python, cookies, tornado

Is there a way to completely disable cookies from the Tornado server?  I'm not using them for my public-facing site and I don't want to have the annoying pop-up to get European compliance.

Answer (score 0):

The only time Tornado sets cookies on its own is if you use the `xsrf_cookies` application setting. If you turn that off and there are no other calls to `set_cookie` or `set_secure_cookie` in your application, no cookies will be set.

XSRF is a serious security issue and you should carefully consider whether you need an alternative solution if you don't use `xsrf_cookies`. However, if you don't have any other cookies (or equivalent forms of authentication), you're probably OK.